How can I create a function in Classic ASP to check if a value is a valid hex color without the `#` or `%23`?
I need a function in Classic ASP that checks if a string is a valid hex color, but the input will not include the # character or %23. For example, the input should be ffcc00 (without # or %23).
I want the function to return True if the string is a valid 6-character hex value (like ffcc00), and False if it’s not a valid hex color.
How can I achieve this, the code below does not seem to work. ?
Example Function:
Function IsHexColor(value)
    Dim regex, match
    Set regex = New RegExp
    regex.Pattern = "^[0-9A-Fa-f]{6}$" ' Check for 6 valid hex characters (0-9, A-F)
    regex.IgnoreCase = True
    regex.Global = False
    Set match = regex.Execute(value)
    If match.Count > 0 Then
        IsHexColor = True
    Else
        IsHexColor = False
    End If
End Function


See this answer.

Why do you need this? If you correctly encode the crosshatch (#) to %23 when passing the bgcolor querystring none of this is necessary as both values named or hex will work. May be first explain why you think this is needed?

Relevant - How to apply dynamic hex color background using ASP query string in a custom domain?

Instead of adding additional questions with no context to your original question, edit the original and provide further context, that way it may be re-opened.
